# Build expression trees to represent if-else

Tags: c#, expression-trees

Deserializing of Expression tree using ExpressionSerialization on a full conditional expression i.e ternary operator is giving error . If i am using ternary operator it causes FullConditionExpression (System Not Supported Exception)

Using code from following links:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/exprserialization

Are there any latest version available for the above link?

http://metalinq.codeplex.com/

Tried this afterwards

```
public Expression<Func<object, string>> LabelCriteria { get; set; }

LabelCriteria = x =>
    {
      if (true)
          return "Cash";
      else      
          return " ";
    }
```

Expression doesn't support if - else block . It gives error as " A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to expression tree . Is there any other way to do it.

Comment: Its just a code snippet. I want to actually use if else-if else-if else .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a method like here:

```
string myFunction(Object obj){
     //here your if-else...
}
```

---

```
LabelCriteria = x => myFunction(x);
```

Answer (score 6):

You must use the conditional operator:

```
LabelCriteria = x => true ? "Cash" : " ";
```

It may be that the compiler is modifying the expression because of constant folding, however, since the condition is a constant expression (`true`).  Try using a variable there and see what happens.

Comment: True is just used for code snippet. It basically checks multiple things to evaluate to true or false. I also wanted to add that i wanna use if else-if else-if else loop.

Comment: @user1650470 you cannot use if-else in an expression lambda.  You can use the conditional operator.  If you have multiple conditions, then use multiple conditional operators: `x => condition1 ? result1 : condition2 ? result2 : condition3 ? result3 : result4;`.  A statement lambda (such as `x => { if (condition1) return result1; else return result2; }`) cannot be converted to an expression tree.

Answer (score 1):

you could construct an expression tree explicitly with Expression API, refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

here's the code for your problem:

```
        ParameterExpression x = Expression.Parameter(typeof (object), "x");
        ConditionalExpression body = Expression.IfThenElse(
            Expression.Constant(true),
            Expression.Constant("Cash"),
            Expression.Constant(" ")
            );

        LabelCriteria = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, string>>(body, x);
```

Comment: Your code throws 'System.ArgumentException : Expression of type 'System.Void' cannot be used for return type 'System.String'. You should use Expression.Condition instead of Expression.IfThenElse.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Ad i was using this particular piece of code

Using code from following links:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/exprserialization

It didn't handle full conditional expression but it handle conditional expression. I just added FullConditionalExpression into the switch case in deserialization and it worked. It was same as ConditionalExpression in the switch.